# Webdriver : No such element: Unable to locate element even after providing wait , But debug mode is executing fine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

no such element: Unable to locate element even after providing wait , But debug mode is executing fine. See the code after 5 second wait. That line is executing fine while debug mode.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("Dental Assistant");
```

Comment: How to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try to find the xpath with a browser first, if is there maybe increase the wait time. For more info please be more concrete about your problem.

Comment: Share `HTML` code.

Comment: @Test Nish Did your query get resolved? If not, can you provide the following info: 1. What are you exactly trying to do? 2. Provide relevant HTML DOM. 3. Show more of your code. 4. Provide a snapshot of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative Xpath instead of absolute xpath if there are any changes made in the path of the element then that absolute XPath gets failed.

- try this by increasing implicit wait time

  `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`